# How can I remove the outer gutter in 3 column grid from bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

See this fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/Nb5C7/

where is the blue gutter on the ends coming from( seems from auto margin) and how can I remove them?

I can remove the gutter if I go fixed grid as in this example
http://bootply.com/93548

but prefer not too

The code from the fiddle

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-4" id="column1x">
One
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="column2x">
Two
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4" id="column3x">
    Three

    </div>
```

and the css

```
     .container, .container-fixed { 
background: #34c6f3;
 }

#column1x, #column2x, #column3x {
-width : 32%;
height: 620px;
margin-right: 0px;
background: #ed1e6c;
border: 1px solid #222;
}   

#column1x, #column2x {
-margin-right: 2%;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add this:

```
.container {
    padding: 0;
}
```

There's some padding coming from the container. If that doesn't overwrite it you can use `!important` but I wouldn't recommend it.

[**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Ruddy/Nb5C7/2/)

Comment: Thanks mate.

thats seems to fix it.

Comment: Np, if you could accept the answer that would be great. (little tick next to my answer)